# How to implement nested *ngFor in angular

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I have json response which looks like below:

```
{
"hotel_name":"name",
"hotel_email":"hotel@gmail.com",
"contractList":[{
             "start_date": "2020-12-2",
             "end-date":"2020-12-10",
           }]
"roomsList":[{
            "type_name":"standard"

             },
             {
            "type_name":"premium"
             }]
}
```

I want to print this to the UI through angular. Therefore I used the following code.

```
<div class="content">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap " fxLayoutGap="50px grid">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels; let i = index;">
  
        <mat-card class="example">
          <mat-card-title>{{ hotel.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>{{ hotel.address1 }}</mat-card-subtitle>

          <div *ngFor="let room of hotel[i].roomsList; let j = index ">
          <mat-card-content >
          
            <p>Room Details</p>
            
            <p style="color: darkcyan;">room[j].type_name</p> 
          </mat-card-content>
        </div>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I am getting this error in the UI console.
[image: error]
What am i doing wrong? Whats the correct way of printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error happened you are trying to access the array element of the hotel (the hotel variable is not an array. It's an object). You can solve the issue by replacing hotel(object) with hotels(array) in second nested loop

```
<div class="content">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap " fxLayoutGap="50px grid">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels; let i = index;">
  
        <mat-card class="example">
          <mat-card-title>{{ hotel.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>{{ hotel.address1 }}</mat-card-subtitle>

          <div *ngFor="let room of hotels[i].roomsList; let j = index ">
          <mat-card-content >
          
            <p>Room Details</p>
            
            <p style="color: darkcyan;">room[j].type_name</p> 
          </mat-card-content>
        </div>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use For-of-Loop for your requirement.

```
<div class="content">
   <div fxLayout="row wrap " fxLayoutGap="50px grid">
      <div class="grid-container">
         <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
            <mat-card class="example">
               <mat-card-title>{{ hotel.name }}</mat-card-title>
               <mat-card-subtitle>{{ hotel.address}}</mat-card-subtitle>
               <div *ngFor="let room of hotel.roomList">
                  <mat-card-content >
                     <p>Room Details</p>
                     <p style="color: darkcyan;">room.type_name</p>
                  </mat-card-content>
               </div>
            </mat-card>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your example json, your code seems wrong.

Replace `let room of hotel[i].roomsList` with `let room of hotel.roomsList`
And `room[j].type_name` with `room.type_name`
In your case you don't need to use counter var like, `i` or `j`.

Your code should be like:

```html
<div class="content">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap " fxLayoutGap="50px grid">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
  
        <mat-card class="example">
          <mat-card-title>{{ hotel.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>{{ hotel.address1 }}</mat-card-subtitle>

          <div *ngFor="let room of hotel.roomsList">
          <mat-card-content >
          
            <p>Room Details</p>
            
            <p style="color: darkcyan;">room.type_name</p> 
          </mat-card-content>
        </div>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try this now, but it was generating an error saying "The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
      The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?"

Comment: Because your json example should be into an array, instead of directly put an object.
Can you please reproduce your issue on https://stackblitz.com/ or https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Why there is I,J parameter is your code without using it. Identify bug first and post reply without providing alternative code with broken variables. It is good to post alternative way but post solution as well. So many developers reading these articles.

Comment: @ChamikaraSamarasekara. Yes you right, i and j is not needed (I edit answer), but this is not brokens variable it's unused variables... And this is not an alternative solution because on the code provided i and j is only use to get value in child, so it's cleaner and more understandable to simply remove it and use "hotel" variable